# How to use child task in nested tasks

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task

I'm running nested tasks using parallel.For . But for one iteration based on certain conditions i have to run a child task attaching that particular iterated task.

below is my sample code.

```
  Dim tsk As Task = Task.Run(Function() Parallel.For(0, dgvDataTables.Rows.Count, New ParallelOptions() With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1},
  Sub(index)
      // performs certion action
    if expression valid then
           Dim childTask As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()                                                                                                                                                  
             // performs action                                                                                                                           
End Sub, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
   end if
  End Sub)
```

When i run my code, the child task is getting executed once all the iterations are completed.

how to attach child task to parent task in nested ?

Any help is appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this case is to use a different overload of `Parallel.For`. There is one that allows you to pass a local variable. This is the one you need.

[`Parallel.For(Of TLocal)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd990379.aspx)

So what you basically want to do inside your outer task is:

```
Dim childTasks As New List(Of Task)
Parallel.For(0, dgvDataTables.Rows.Count,
             New ParallelOptions() With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1},
             Function() New List(Of Task),
             Function(index, state, taskList)
               // performs certion action
               If expression valid Then
                 Dim childTask = Task.Run(Sub()
                                            // performs action 
                                          End Sub)  
                 taskList.Add(childTask)
               End If
               Return taskList                      
             End Function,
             Sub(taskList)
               SyncLock childTasks
                 childTasks.AddRange(taskList)
               End SyncLock
             End Sub)
Task.WaitAll(childTasks.ToArray())
```

So the basic idea is to collect all the task into one list and wait for all collected tasks once the `Parallel.For` is done.

I deliberately chose to usage of `Task.WaitAll` here, because using `Await` and `Task.WhenAll` may cause problems together with `Parallel.For`. I tend to avoid mixing the `Parallel` functions and `Async/Await`.

All that said and done, I have to warn you that this code may create a massive overhead, depending on how many `Task` instances you are creating. If there are too many active running `Task` instances, the performance of your application will break down.